# Javascript is returning html instead json

Tags: javascript, node.js, bitbucket, fetch-api

I am trying to connect to bitbucket and gather the commits. I tried the below code.

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

async function neww(){
    await fetch('https://bitbucketexample.com/projects/CD/repos/central-msp-config/commits', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/xml',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer YXIxMjAwOldlbGNvbWUxMDkqCg=='
  }
}).then((data)=>{
    console.log(data.status)
    return data.body();
}).then(text => console.log(text))
}

neww()
```

I am expecting it to return json with commit details while I am receiving the html of the page.
Would appreciate your help in fixing this., Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you expect that URL to return JSON? Do you have some documentation that says it should return JSON instead of HTML?

Comment: you're expecting json but your header has 'Accept': 'application/xml' .... maybe that's why the BE api is sending you xml response, since i've no idea about the API I can't say for sure though.... but try 'Accept': 'application/json'

Comment: @Quentin I am able to get the output as a json with all the commits needed when python is used but not happening with js , I wanna achieve it with javascript

Comment: @cicada_ it would have been okay if it had returned html or any format with the commit details but the data returned doesn’t make sense

Answer (score 0):

You're expecting json but your request header has `'Accept': 'application/xml'`

Try changing it to `'Accept': 'application/json'`

That should fix it.

Comment: That’s a typo , I’m actually using application/json.

Comment: @AbilashKrishnan can you share the documentation of the api you're using?